# how add css and js to spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to add CSS to my HTML page in Spring Boot using Thymeleaf, added the CSS file in static folder and linked it that way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/home.css}" href="../../css/home.css" />
```

but it doesn't work.

---

I wanted to stop accessing CSS and js in the URL so I added this method to my security configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web
      .ignoring()
      .antMatchers("/resources/static/**"); // #3
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's my error or if any configuration needed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.css` and `.js` are static resources and Spring Boot maps it by default in your `/resources/static` folder

For example:

There is a `style.css` file that is located in `/resources/static/css/style.css`

If you want to access it throught thymeleaf add this to your html head section:

```
<link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Just an observation here, if your are using `@EnableWebMvc` annotation then you should map the static resources by your own configuration.

**EDIT**

*i wanted to stop accessing CSS and js in the URL so I added this method to my security configuration*

All the resources should get access from browser otherwise the `.css` and `.js` will not be loaded.

If you need to get access to the resources only for authenticated users you can try the following configuration:

1. Go to the `/resources/static` folder and create two sub-folders, One for resources for anonymous users `public` and other for authenticated users `private`.
2. Put all public resources to the  `/resources/static/public` folder.
3. Put all private resources  to the  `/resources/static/private` folder.
4. Go to your Spring Security Configuration Class and make your `/private` url private with this configuration: `.antMatchers( "/private/**").authenticated()` and make `/public` accessible for anonymous users: `.antMatchers( "/public/**").permitAll()`

Example for the security configuration:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/private/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()

        ;
    }
}
```

Finally try to access the public resources, for example if you have a `style.css` file under public folder, then try to access it: `http://localhost:808/public/style.css`, the browser should display the style.css content.

When you try to access the private folder (without authentication), for example there is a private.css under private folder then try it: `http://localhost:808/private/private.css`.  You should get redirected to login page, that means that you should login first and after that spring will let you to access to `private.css` resource.

Regarding to thymeleaf it is the same approach, for public html pages use the public resources: `<link th:href="@{/public/public.css}" rel="stylesheet" />` and for protected resources user private soruces `<link th:href="@{/private/syle.css}" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: if you want to use the tag `th`, you have to replace the `<html>` to `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`