# Custom .css file doesn't work with Thymeleaf & Spring MVC

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

So, I've spent like last hour trying to solve it, but I just can't get custom .css file to get linked with html files in [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) 5. I'm using Thymeleaf, [Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) & [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) for frontend works. I'm using Intellij Community Edition.

My files hierarchy looks like this:

```
java
    project_files
resources
    static
        css
          main.css
    templates
        main.html
```

I have a line in `main.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" href="../../css/main.css"/>
```

that should link my styles with the .html file. What can be wrong?

Comment: *"What may be wrong?"* -- about half a million things "may be wrong". Do you want a list of all of them? I don't think so. [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon i.e. post the **HTML output** for the entire page including css links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how add css and js to spring boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536972/how-add-css-and-js-to-spring-boot-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf + CSS+SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586841/thymeleaf-cssspringboot)

Comment: Look in your DevToools Network tab what URL is requested, it will be relative to the URL of the page requesting it and is not dependent on the location of your templates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing a little bit your folder structure, create a folder under resources called **static**, and a folder called **css** under static and place the css files there, something like:

```
 resources
└───  static
    └───  css
        └─── main.css
```

Then you should be able to access it by using:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
```

Comment: I do it, but give warnmessage and page is not changed by css file. message: o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /css/style.css

Comment: I add that: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>

Comment: @Nasta please open a question in order to providde enough information about what is happening