# Spring Boot - Only allow authenticated users to access resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a simple Spring Boot application with a directory like this:

```
+ src
  + main
    + java
    + resources
      + public
         + images
            - dog.png
      + private
         + images
            - cat.png
      + templates
         - home.html
         - login.html
```

Resources in the public folder can be accessed by everyone. I want to make resources in the private folder to be only accessed by authenticated users.

For example, `home.html` can only be accessed by authenticated users, which has an image `cat.png`. If an unauthorized user tries to directly access the resource via `https://localhost:8080/private/images/cat.png` then the server will reject the request.

My `WebSecurityConfig.java` :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resources/private/images/cat.png").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(encoder.encode("password")).roles("USER");
    }

}
```

I've also tried using `antMatchers.("/resources/private/**").authenticated()` as well, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: issue could be url pattern is /private/images/cat.png and you are adding /resources/private/ in your WebSecurityConfig

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537528/6572971 might help you.

Comment: Your URL is wrong. There is no `/resources` as that is part of the classpath. So remove the `/resources` from the url mapping. Also you want to move the first line to just before the `anyRequest`.. Ordering of security rules is important as that is also the order they are consulted in. Also `home.html` is accessible by anyone according to your security configuration.